# F# backgroundTask cause WPF UI freezing

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, f#

I have a WPF application (.NET 8) in C#. This application calls a function in a F# library, this F# function starts a task using the backgroundTask computation expression:

```
let fun1() = ignore <| backgroundTask {
// long asynchronous work, no access elements, only internal memory
}
```

By using the `backgroundTask` instead of the `task` CE, I would expect that the task runs on a separated thread and [doesn't affect the responsiveness of the GUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/task-expressions#background-tasks).
This is not the case though, the GUI still freezes while that task is running.

What's wrong?

Comment: backgroundTask modifies the SynchronizatiionContext which will dictates how/where resumption happens after an Async piece has been executed. Where execution _starts_ is still your job, i.e. the opening synchronous piece will run in/on whatever thread you run it on, unless you do something specific to move off whatever thread you're on. In othe words, `Task.Run`, or any other way in which you can grab a threadpool thread. Also if it's truly long running, consider the guidance in https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md re details of that

Answer (score 2):

What is the value of `SynchronizationContext.Current` in your scenario?

From the [F# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/task-expressions#background-tasks):

> A background task ignores any `SynchronizationContext.Current` in the following sense: if started on a thread with non-null `SynchronizationContext.Current`, it switches to a background thread in the thread pool using `Task.Run`. If started on a thread with null `SynchronizationContext.Current`, it executes on that same thread.

Given this explanation, I suspect you have a null `SynchronizationContext.Current`, so your code is running on the thread that started it. (I find this behavior surprising as well, but at least it's documented.)

Comment: When starting the background task, SynchronizationContext.Current is not null

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I finally got the desired fluidity in the GUI. This is what I found:

- Release builds have less freezing side effects than Debug
- Starting the process with the debugger attached (F5 in Visual studio), worsens the freezing effect
- The code in the task is iterating an IAsyncEnumerable<_>. Initially I was using [TaskSeq](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.TaskSeq). I removed it an wrote the iteration using the enumerator and a built-in async CE. This improved the results as well.

Now, If I run my new code (no TaskSeq), Release build, without Debugger attached, freezing doesn't occur at all (or it is imperceptible).